# Assembly not found for framework xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I get an error compiling on visual studio for mac : Failed to resolve 'insert_assemblyname.type' reference from 'insert_assembly'. When I check the package in solution explorer there is an error icon. Mousing over tells me: "Assembly not found for framework xamarin.ios"

However, I can build the same solution from the PC just fine.

On the Mac I'm running macOS High Sierra v10.13.4 with XCode 9.3 (14154) and Visual Studio fro Mac 7.4.2 with Xamarin.ios 11.9.1.24

On PC I've got Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 v15.6.4 with v4.7.02046 of .NET Framework and Xamarin.iOS 11.8.1.28

I can't figure out the underlying issue here, any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

select your project and go to the ios build option from there choose linker and set it to access SDK from assembly only. then try to build your solution.

Or you have to update your XCode 9.3 to a higher version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Android "assembly not found for framework xamarin.android 7.1", and I had to delete the "obj" and "bin" folders from the project folder, restart Visual Studio, and finally, rebuilt the project. You can try this for iOS and see if it works.